# Retrieve String from nested JSON - System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, json

I am using a JSON Object to get news titles from various websites. When I unpack it I can access one title but when i try to loop over the items and add them to a list to get all titles I get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

I am using newtonsoft.json and then make it into a dynamic object in order to get access through dot notation.

JSON Example

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 10,
    "articles": [{
        "source": {
            "id": "bloomberg",
            "name": "Bloomberg"
        },
        "author": null,
        "title": "Here’s Where the GOP Tax Plan Stands Right Now",
        "description": "The House is scheduled to vote Tuesday on the tax bill and Senate leaders intend to bring the measure up as soon as they get it.",
        "url": "http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-12-19/house-plans-early-vote-democrats-plan-drama-tax-debate-update",
        "urlToImage": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/isN9fqUqLwpE/v0/1200x800.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2017-12-19T09:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "source": {
            "id": "bloomberg",
            "name": "Bloomberg"
        },
        "author": "Dana Hull, Sarah Frier",
        "title": "Elon Musk Appears to Have Misfired Direct Message to Oculus CTO",
        "description": "Elon Musk appears to have just given his 16.7 million Twitter followers what he meant to send to the co-founder of the virtual-reality company Oculus: his phone number.",
        "url": "http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-12-19/elon-musk-appears-to-have-misfired-direct-message-to-oculus-cto",
        "urlToImage": "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iqJHjveOq1j8/v1/1200x740.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2017-12-19T21:41:36Z"
    }]
}
```

code:

```
// Set base Website
var url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=";
// Initiate Client
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
// Get JSON Data
var json = client.DownloadString(url + site + apiKey);
// Convert to dynamic object
dynamic jOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
// Get Articles
var articles = jOutput.articles;
//Declare List
List<String> titles = new List<String>();
foreach (var article in articles)
 {
   var  articleTitle = article.title;
   titles.Add(articleTitle);       
 }

string title = jOutput.articles[0].title;
//string txt = items[0].title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft will actually provide you `JValue` items when you're deserializing into an object or dynamic type.

So, this line here:

```
var articleTitle = article.title;
```

`articleType` is of type `JValue`, not `string`. Thus, when you call `List<string>.Add(articleType)` - it fails, as there's no overload accepting a `JValue`.

Luckily, `JValue` has overloaded cast operators which allow you to unwrap the actual value. Simply changing the above line to:

```
string articleTitle = article.title;
```

Is enough to get your code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still not getting the values in a list but rather I'm getting 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @phil.pidis Are you sure the above JSON is exactly what you're parsing? Because your result would imply that title is actually an array of strings, rather than a string. Or, *where* are you getting that text? If you're trying to `Console.WriteLine(titles)`, that's to be expected.

Comment: Sorry @Rob was editing. the above was meant to say'yes it is the same JSON. No I'm not doing Console.WriteLine(titles) but I am trying to show the data on another platform which might actually be the problem! thanks will check this now'

Comment: Have been troubleshooting but I'm still getting the same result. Cant get to the values in the list..

Comment: @phil.pidis What is in the list when you debug it? Before you get to the presentation layer. Putting a breakpoint on `string title = jOutput.articles[0].title;` with my change, and inspecting the list, should have the values you're expecting. I've just tested it locally with your JSON blob.

Comment: @ Rob got it working. I had some wrong data matching further down the line which was set to item instead of list! Thanks for the help