# Converting jarray to IEnumerable gives "does not contain a definition for Concat"

Tags: c#, json, json.net, ienumerable

I've got the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("[\"test1\", \"test2\"]");
        var list = json.ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>().Concat(new[] { "test3" });
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    }
}
```

I would expect the result to be "test1, test2, test3" but instead this throws an exception:

> [Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Concat']
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String[] )
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
> at Program.Main() :line 10

As far as I can tell in testing, both sides of the `Concat` should be a version of `IEnumerable<string>`.

I've gotten a successful try doing this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("[\"test1\", \"test2\"]");
        var list = (json as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Select(item => (string)item).Concat(new[] { "test3" });
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    }
}
```

But that's a bit clunky.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: It almost all cases, avoid the use of `dynamic`. It's a compiler trick to introduce hidden run-time bugs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Borrowing the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897343/retrieve-string-from-nested-json-system-collections-generic-list1system-stri), I tried assigning the output of ToObject() method to a new variable with explicit type like so:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("[\"test1\", \"test2\"]");
        IEnumerable<string> jsonAsEnumerable = json.ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>();
        var list = jsonAsEnumerable.Concat(new[] { "test3" });
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    }
}
```

It seems to do the trick.

Comment: Oh, yeah that works. And the type has to be explicitly stated it seems (`IEnumerable<string>` not just `var`). Strange - thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you could avoid `dynamic` and deserialize to `IEnumerable<string>` directly

Comment: In this case, I could. But this is just a simple example of my bigger use case

Comment: The problem is that `IEnumerable.Concat` is an extension method, not a method of `IEnumerable` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-7.0). Dynamic can find the methods an object implements, but not extension methods. You'll need to cast/convert your `dynamic` to a collection for this to work. Sorry, but `.ToList` and `ToArray` won't work here either (extension methods, too)

Comment: @derekantrican: you say _"not just var"_. Note that `var` isn't a type. It's a stand-in for whatever the type of the right-hand-side of the assignment. Using `var` isn't a way to say a variable is kinda-sorta type-less. It's just a way to save you typing on your keyboard (and it's needed for anonymously typed objects - which are fully typed, but with an unknown type)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was super simple to fix. Here it is:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>("[\"test1\", \"test2\"]");
var list = json.Concat(new[] { "test3" });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

You just needed to change `dynamic` to `dynamic[]`.

Remember that `dynamic` is just compiler trickery for `object`-that-doesn't-throw-compiler-errors. But it isn't something that is enumerable. However, `dynamic[]` is.

But for that matter, `object[]`, and even `string[]`, works.

```
string[] json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>("[\"test1\", \"test2\"]");
IEnumerable<string> list = json.Concat(new[] { "test3" });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

My advice is avoid `dynamic` in almost all cases. Use strong-typing instead.

Comment: Yes, that would fix this example, but I need to use `dynamic` for my larger project (this is only a minimal example). I'm deserializing a larger json object to a `dynamic` and grabbing individual properties